# Answering debconf questions from a custom GUI in Python? (Custom Front-end)

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I'm writing an app that should enable the user to install some additional packages when needed. I'd like to create a custom GUI that collects the packages debconf questions along with some other questions from my app. I'll then install the package using aptd or something and any questions asked by the package install script will be answered by fields in my custom GUI.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `debconf-set-selections` command from the `debconf-utils` package is suitable for this.

The format is simple: `debconf-set-selections [filename]`

If filename is not provided, then it takes its input from stdin. The format for the answer lines themselves are also simple: `< packagename> < question_name> < datatype> < value>`.

So, if you wanted to install the `mysql-server` using a predetermined password, then you'd create a file such as this one (mysql-prefs.seed)

```
mysql-server-5.5    mysql-server/root_password          password    my_root_password
mysql-server-5.5    mysql-server/root_password_again    password    my_root_password
```

Then you insert these answers into the debconf database by running `debconf-set-selections mysql-prefs.seed`. Finally, you just install the package as normal: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server -yq` and the MySQL root user's password will now be "my_root_password".

I don't know if this is the *best* way to do it, but it certainly works and it's easy enough.